# Eth recovery from a created eth smart contract

Tags: remix

I created an eth contract address with a video I saw on YouTube and sent 1 eth there. The problem is that I can't get back 1 eth. Please help me get it back.
Smart contract address I created;. https://etherscan.io/address/0xae9db035bbd9344eeada6f8bcd3ffc84e76d1306

youtube video link https://youtu.be/Vhkb9G2SyVw smart contract code link; https://pastebin.com/raw/JrApmW5p

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but it is a scam. You cannot get it back. There have been multiple reports of it. I reverse-engineered it for you. When the withdrawal function is called, the funds from your contract will be sent to this address: [**0xBcF87A18e05e562BD307d76682677d2388973cc6**](https://etherscan.io/address/0xBcF87A18e05e562BD307d76682677d2388973cc6). I hope that helps you how somehow.

Comment: Dude I'm the smart contract owner and the funds are in the smart contract. Is there a way to recover funds as I am the founder?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are an owner or deployer. There is no implicit functionality to reclaim funds as owner or deployer. You need to specify explicitly how funds are transferred from a contract. In this case, funds can be transferred solely to the address I posted above.

Comment: If I contact Ethereum, will they help me get the funds back?

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody can do that. That's not how blockchain works.

Comment: thank you for your attention. I'm so sorry I lost my money.